# Using Provider when a callback function is used

Tags: flutter, mqtt

I need some advice how to use Provider when you get data back from a callback function.
My aim is to use Provider to update all Widgets instead of passing the data returned from the callback all the way down to all Widgets.

In example code below I create an instance of the class MQTTClientWrapper. I provide two callback functions. One of the callback functions is "mqttMessageReceived", which is called by the MQTTClientWrapper instance when new data arrives. Using a simple setState I can update the value of the Widget. But what if the top Widget has other Widgets that need to be updated too? The only thing I can think of is passing the received data to the Widgets as arguments.

How could I use Provider to update only those Widgets that needs to be updated?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'mqttClientWrapper.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'MQTT test1',
      home: MqttHomePage(title: 'Flutter MQTT test1'),
    );
  }
}

class MqttHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MqttHomePage({Key? key, this.title = ''}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MqttHomePageState createState() => _MqttHomePageState();
}

class _MqttHomePageState extends State<MqttHomePage> {
  var clientIdentifier = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  late MQTTClientWrapper mqttClientWrapper;
  String connectionStatus = 'Connecting';
  String messageReceived = '-';

  void setup() {
    mqttClientWrapper = MQTTClientWrapper((status) => mqttStatus(status), (message) => mqttMessageReceived(message));
    mqttClientWrapper.prepareMqttClient();
  }

  void mqttStatus(MqttCurrentConnectionState connectionState) {
    String status = '';
    print('Connection status: ' + connectionState.toString());
    if (connectionState == MqttCurrentConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
      status = 'Connected';
    } else if (connectionState == MqttCurrentConnectionState.CONNECTING) {
      status = 'Connecting...';
    } else if (connectionState == MqttCurrentConnectionState.DISCONNECTED) {
      status = 'Disconnected';
    } else {
      status = 'Unknown error';
    }
    setState(() {
      connectionStatus = status;
    });
  }

  void mqttMessageReceived(String message) {
    print('Message: ' + message);
    setState(() {
      messageReceived = message;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setup();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Status: '),
              Text(
                connectionStatus,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 100.0),
          Text(
            messageReceived,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 100.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Change notifier provider here .
inside the function call change the state of the provider and watch the same provider where ever you need(to get the value).

for more info

[how to use provider + ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html)

I hope its useful.

Comment: Thanks, but how would you change the state of the provider in that callback function if you don't have the context available?